# Using Python to download api data

Tags: python, csv

Hi I have created a piece of code that downloads data from a api end point and also loads in the apikeys.

I am trying to achieve downloading the api data into csv files into their own folder based on the input.csv I have tried to achieve this by adding the following section at the end. The problem is that it does not download the file its to be receiving from the api end point.

Please assist?

```
with open('filepath/newfile.csv', 'w+') as f:
    f.write(r.text)
```

```
import csv
import sys
import requests
def query_api(business_id, api_key):
    headers = {
        "Authorization": api_key
    }
    r = requests.get('https://api.link.com', headers=headers)
    print(r.text)
# get filename from command line arguments
if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print ("input.csv")
    sys.exit(1)
csv_filename = sys.argv[1]
with open(csv_filename) as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    for row in csv_reader:
        business_id = row['BusinessId']
        api_key = row['ApiKey']
        query_api(business_id, api_key)
with open('filepath/newfile.csv', 'w+') as f:
    f.write(r.text)
```

Comment: What goes wrong? Your code has several steps, can you narrow the code to a working example that demonstrates the problem? For instance, if the problem is in `query_api`, focus on that. I notice that function doesn't return any data, so even if the api call succeeds, its data is lost.

Comment: It doesnt provide any errors it just says input.csv when i try to run the piece of code

Comment: How did you call the script? It looks like you call the script without parameters. `sys.argv[0]` is the name of the script and arguments 1 (and etc...) are command line parameters you supply. If you don't supply parameters, then `len(sys.argv)` is `1`. Your code checks that, prints "input.csv" and then exits.